# I need to automaticlly add a link to email sent by community users?

Tags: apex, trigger, community, email, lightning-experience

Is there a way to let customer community plus users use lighting email template?
Or is there way to update the body of an email before sending it ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Both of these things are possible if the email is sent via custom Apex. I am not sure if there is a direct way for community users to see an email template, however. What is your use case? Do you want users to write a message that then gets included in a template when it is sent?

Comment: I need to add a link to the email sent by community users

Answer (score 0):

Email templates are intended to be used with a related record, so one possibility here is to enable your community users to set a field on a record with the URL you want them to set, save it, then send the email with the field exposed in it. This approach lessens the amount of code you would need to write, but it would consume a field from some object in your org.

If you don't want to save the URL, you can use the `Messaging` class to send emails via Apex and even dynamically set your email body without a record. Below are two approaches. One leverages the `renderStoredEmailTemplate` to take advantage of your existing email template (it will auto-fill the merge fields for you). Two is just a straightforward email sent via Apex.

I've left various methods up to you to implement (e.g. `getEmailTemplateId`, `getRelatedObjectId`, `getHtmlEmailBody`) as needed for your use-case.

```
// Approach #1, create a VF email template and replace a portion of its body with the URL
// Benefits:
// - you get the flexibility of a VF template (can include a related object)
//
// Downsides:
// - rendering VF templates consumes DML, so this is unfit for bulkification in most scenarios
@AuraEnabled
public static void sendEmail(String myUrl) {
    Id emailTemplateId = getEmailTemplateId();
    Id recipientId = getRecipientId(); //whoId, assuming the recipient is a Contact, Lead, or User
    Id relatedObjectId = getRelatedObjectId(); //whatId

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(emailTemplateId, recipientId, relatedObjectId);
    String emailHtmlBody = email.getHtmlBody();
    // String.format expects the string to be replaced is `{0}`, so it will be needed in your template
    emailHtmlBody = String.format(emailHtmlBody, new String[]{
        myUrl
    });

    String emailTextBody = email.getPlainTextBody();
    emailTextBody = String.format(emailTextBody, new String[]{
        myUrl
    });

    email.setPlainTextBody(emailTextBody);
    email.setHtmlBody(emailHtmlBody);

    List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(email);
    if(!results.get(0).isSuccess()) {
        // ... handle error scenario
    }
}
```

```
// Approach #2, create email body entirely in Apex with the URL
// Benefits:
// - you do not need to specify a relatedObjectId (whatId) if you do not need one
//
// Downsides:
// - harder to maintain as the email body is assembled in code
@AuraEnabled
public static void sendEmail(String myUrl) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    Id recipientId = getRecipientId();
    email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{recipientId});

    // assemble the email body in `getHtmlEmailBody`
    String htmlEmailBody = getHtmlEmailBody(myUrl);
    email.setHtmlBody(htmlEmailBody);

    // optionally assemble a plain text body
    String plainTextEmailBody = getPlainTextEmailBody(myUrl);
    email.setPlainTextBody(plainTextEmailBody);
    email.setSubject('Some Subject');

    List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(email);
    if(!results.get(0).isSuccess()) {
        // ... handle error scenario
    }
}
```

Documentation:

- [Messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Messaging.htm)
- [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm)